# C++ Overload & Override - cannot initialize a parameter of type '' with an rvalue of type ''

Tags: c++, overloading, overriding

I'm normally a C# guy, and it handles this fine, largely under its handling of "best match" resolving the method to call. I'm trying to do something similar in C++ now, but am getting a compile error. Long story short, it's a combination of method *overloading* **and** *overriding*.

class Bar : public Foo { }  //Contents don't really matter here

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void Do(Foo* foo) { }
    virtual void Do(Bar* bar) { }
};
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    virtual void Do(Bar* bar) { }
}


Foo* foo = new Foo();
Derived* d = new Derived();
d->Do(foo); //cannot initialize a parameter of type 'Bar*' with an rvalue of type 'Foo*'
```

So, it tries to resolve the method against *only* the methods in `Derived` rather than recognizing the base class implements a valid match. Again, C# finds the base method. Can C++ not do this, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A function in a derived class *hides* any functions of the same name in a base class (even if you're overriding a virtual function).  To unhide the other overloads, use a "`using`" statement:

```
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    virtual void Do(Bar* bar) { }
    using Base::Do;
};
```

Comment: TIL, thanks. I'm on my phone at the moment but does Java work the same way?

Comment: Java resolves the same as C# in this, requiring no extra syntax to avoid "name hiding."